# Custom Fields after update to WordPress 6

Tags: custom-field, block-editor, upgrade

I had a site where posts had custom fields and upgraded to WordPress 6 recently.
However, now I cannot find the custom fields in the back-end.
They still display correctly in the front-end, so the data is there somewhere.

I am not using a custom field plugin, these were just custom fields added manually in the Custom Field panel in the older version of WordPRess.

Gutenberg no longer has any custom field options when clicking the 3 dots it seems, so mentions of that must have been in older tutorials.

Any idea how I can view custom fields in the back-end again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the top right corner, click on Options, from there click on Preferences. Now select Panels from the left side of the prefs window and you'll find an option to toggle custom fields listed under Additional.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hmmm, I don't have the "Custom fields" option....

Comment: Oh! I figured it out. For people who are looking for this, if you have ACF installed, you need to add the following to your functions.php

`add_filter('acf/settings/remove_wp_meta_box', '__return_false');`